icons don't show their original design colours
I've implemented a bottom navigation on my main activity view and set four icons in it, some are an orange shade and one has two colors: magenta and orange. There is something interfering with them displaying their original colours and would go dark grey for inactive icons and I believe black when they go active.
I've tried setting the app:itemIconTint to @null but then they take the color thats defined in the themes.xml file, before no colour was defined and icons showed a lavender colour. Icons have different colours.
mainActivity menu_yo vector image original color
colors xml

Define custom colors for your icons like this:
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
...
app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color"
... />

And in your colors.xml:
<color name="bottom_nav_icon_color">@null</color>

Changing colors when icons become active or inactive, you can specify different colors for these states in your XML:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/active_icon_color" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@color/inactive_icon_color" />

Themes:
If you're still seeing unexpected colors, check your theme settings. Sometimes, themes can override specific settings like icon colors.

tried it but anywhere I try to apply @null tint it inherits some color from I don't know where that looks purple, my guess is it has something to do with the menu_yo.xml because the header has that same colour. thanks for the response. I added some images, they're four, first show my main_activity, second shows the menu_yo.xml, third shows the vector image original coloring and the last one shows my colors.xml file
